# On a conjecture that $\sum_{i=1}\limits^na_ip_i = 1\Rightarrow \exists\big(\sum_{i=1}\limits^na_i=0\big)$ (about primes)

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, prime-numbers, conjectures

> > **Conjecture:**
>
> Denote by $p_i$ the $i^{\text{th}}$ prime number; by $a_i$ the $i^\text{th}$ arbitrary integer; and by $\exists(x)$ the existence of a chosen $x$.$$\sum_{i=1}^na_ip_i = 1\Rightarrow \exists\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^na_i=0\bigg)\tag{$n>1$}$$ In words: if the sum of an arbitrary quantity of successive prime numbers each multiplied by an integer is equal to $1$, then there exists a solution for which the sum of strictly all such integers is equal to $0$.

Examples:

$$\begin{align} 2(-1) + 3(1) &= 1 \tag{$-1+1=0$} \\ 2(1)+3(-2)+5(1)&=1\tag{$1-2+1=0$} \\ 2(1)+3(-3)+5(3)+7(-1)&=1\tag{$1-3+3-1=0$} \\ 2(-1)+3(2)+5(0)+7(-2)+11(1)&=1\tag{$-1+2+0-2+1=0$}\\&\vdots\end{align}$$

Even better: I have potentially found a method to find such integer coefficients! It is difficult to explain, but I will try my best. Once you get it, it should be all-good.

---

Consider the difference of the second and first prime: $3-2=1$ (always subtract from the bigger number, albeit this has already been done). Or, $$\underbrace{p_2}_{3}-\underbrace{p_1}_{2}=1.\tag1$$ This is all we did:

$3-2=1 = Eq. (1)$

Now, consider the difference of the third and second prime: $5-3=2$. But also consider the overall difference of: this result (which is $2$) and $3-2$ (which is $1$). This should give you $2-1$ which is $1$. Equivalently, we have: $$\underbrace{\underbrace{(p_3-p_2)}_{5\,-\,3\,=\,\color{red}2}-\underbrace{(p_2-p_1)}_{3\,-\,2\,=\,\color{red}1}}_{\color{red}2\,-\,\color{red}1\,=\,1}= p_3-p_2-p_2+p_1 = p_3-2p_2+p_1 = 1.\tag2$$ This is all we did:

$5-3=2$. 
 $2-(3-2)=1\Rightarrow (5-3)-(3-2)= Eq. (2)$

Thirdly, consider the difference of the fourth and third prime: $7-5=2$. But also consider the difference of: this result (which is $2$) and $5-3$ (which $2$). This should give you $2-2=0$. Now *also* consider the difference of: this result (which is $0$) and $p_3-2p_2+p_1$ (which is $1$). But remember to subtract from the biggest number, so instead of obtaining $0-1=-1$, we get $1-0=1$. Equivalently, we have: $$p_3-2p_2+p_1-\underbrace{\big(\underbrace{(p_4-p_3)}_{7\,-\,5\,=\,\color{red}2}-\underbrace{(p_3-p_2)}_{5\,-\,3\,=\,\color{red}2}\big)}_{\color{red}2\,-\,\color{red}2\,=\,0}=\cdots =p_1-3p_2+3p_3-p_4=1.\tag3$$

This is all we did:

$7-5=2$. 
 $2-(5-3)=0$. 
 $0 - (p_3-2p_2+p_1)=-1$ and then reversed subtraction because $p_3-2p_2+p_1 > 0$. 
 $(p_3-2p_2+p_1)-0=1\Rightarrow (p_3-2p_2+p_1) - (2-(5-3))=Eq. (3)$

Notice that all the equations $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ are respectively identical to the first three examples of my conjecture (but just rearranged and notated differently)! Each equation is equal to $1$, and the sum of strictly all the integer coefficients in each equation is each equal to $0$.

But did you notice the pattern to the method? Let's continue once more!

$11-7 = 4$. 
 $4 - (7-5) = 2$. 
 $2 - ((7-5)-(5-3))=2$. 
 $2-(p_1-3p_2+3p_3-p_4)=1\Rightarrow 2 - ((7-5)-(5-3)) - (p_1-3p_2+3p_3-p_4)=Eq. (4)$ below (after $p_i$ substitution).

$$\begin{align}&p_1 - \big((p_4-p_3)-(p_3-p_2)\big)-(p_1-3p_2+3p_3-p_4) \\ &=-p_1+2p_2+0p_3-2p_4+p_5\\&=1.\end{align}\tag4$$

It is clear that $Eq. (4)$ is the fourth example of my conjecture.

---

If you understood the pattern of my method, great! If not, we can discuss it (hopefully in clearer detail) in a chat. I am young so my explanation skills might not be that great.

In fact, this method is not that great (either); it quickly becomes incredibly tedious. Firstly, it requires [*Gilbreath's Conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbreath%27s_conjecture) to be true (i.e. that $1$ has to always be there in my conjecture) and secondly, the algebra gets messy.

Does anyone have any comments on this? I mean, why does this method even (seem to) work?

---

Thank you in advance, and apologies for a long post.

Comment: With some effort you could probably generalize the conjecture for any set of coprime integers (which need not be pairwise coprime).

Comment: I wouldn't know how to approach it, but I'll try giving it a shot. Thanks for the suggestion! :P

Comment: You forgot to mention applications for it.  In order to get mathematicians excited about it, you have to mention that.

Comment: Do you allow $a_i = 0$?

Comment: @BananaCats yes; my fourth example is $2(-1)+3(2)+5(0)+7(-2)+11(1)=1$ where the coefficient of the third prime (namely $5$) is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is true. Suppose that one set of solutions is given by $A_i$. As the equation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ip_i=1$ is Diophantine, one can show that the general solution is given by $a_1=A_1+\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1}t_rp_{r+1}$ and $a_k=A_k-p_1t_{k-1}$ where $t_r$ are some integers to be determined and $1<k\le n$. Now $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i=\sum_{i=1}^nA_i+\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1}t_rp_{r+1}-\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}p_1t_r=0$$ from the constraint. Since $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nA_i=0$, it is sufficient to solve $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1}(p_{r+1}-p_1)t_r=0$ for $t_r$. This can be rewritten as $(p_2-p_1)t_1+\sum\limits_{r=2}^{n-1}(p_{r+1}-p_1)t_r=0\implies \sum\limits_{r=2}^{n-1}(p_{r+1}-p_1)t_r=2$ after letting $t_1=-2$ and noting that $p_2-p_1=3-2=1$. This new Diophantine equation has infinitely many solutions for $t_r$, where $1<r\le n$.

Comment: I much prefer this answer, albeit I was a bit slow at fully grasping what was said here. But... if this conjecture is true... then did you just prove [*Gilbreath's Conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbreath%27s_conjecture)??? If my conjecture is true, then since it requires GC to be true, that means...

Comment: Putting that aside, however, nice answer! $(+1)\,\color{green}{\checkmark}$ (second time in a row, yay!) The only problem is, it does not appear to explain why my method works, but that's ok; though, if you are interested, is it ok if you could touch on that a bit more in particular?

Comment: I didn't prove that conjecture, just because conjecture B is a consequence of conjecture A does not mean that you can't prove conjecture B without using conjecture A, and does not mean that conjecture A is proven :)

Comment: Also I have a feeling that this answer has some minor flaws to it - if someone can find them it would be great as well

Comment: Oh, ok. I also don't think I see any flaws :\

Answer (score 2):

Assume that we are given

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ip_i=1$$

with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=M$.

Suppose we produce a solution of $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ip_i=0$$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=-M$. Then replacing $a_i$ by $a_i+x_i$ we get a new solution of the first equation in which the sum of the coefficients is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+x_i)=M-M=0$.

Let's distinguish two cases:

For $n$ odd there is always the solution $x_i=-1$ for $i=2,...,n$ and $x_1=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=2}^{n}p_i$. But then you can add $2M$ to $x_2$ and subtract $3M$ to $x_1$ to get a new solution $(x_1-3M)2+(x_2+2M)3+x_3p_3+...+x_np_n=0$ such that $$(x_1-3M)+(x_2+2M)+x_3+...+x_n=-M$$

For $n$ even we can start from the solution $x_i=-1$ for $i=3,4,...,n$, $x_2=-2$ and $x_1=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=2}^{n}x_i$. Then we do the same modification as before. We add $2M$ to $x_2$ and subtract $3M$ from $x_1$.